# How to display files and applications activity?

Tags: zeitgeist, gnome-activity-journal

I would like to display the activity recorded by Zeitgeist on my Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install [gnome-activity-journal [image: Install gnome-activity-journal]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-activity-journal), and ensure that you have file activity recording turned on in your system settings.

Answer (score 1):

Just enter Pivacy settings in the Ubuntu Dash and turn off the button saying "Register Activity" in the down right corner.

[image]